# How to fix Laravel request/routes/urls - it thinks url is http when it is really https

Tags: laravel, http, https, routes

My server uses SSL and thus all my routes/urls use https. I recently discovered a bug in Laravel 5.7 which was exposed when trying to use Email Verification, which does not work on a server with https. I wont go into the specifics of that problem as I have another question for that. I want to keep this simple.
I have the following settings in my .env file:

```
APP_USE_HTTPS=true
APP_URL=https://www.example.com
APP_ENV=production
```

And I have the following in the boot() method of the AppServiceProvider

```
    if (env('APP_USE_HTTPS')) {
        Log::info('AppServiceProvider: forcing URLs to use https');
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

And it may be overkill but to try to resolve the issue I also put the following code at the top of my web.php routes file"

```
if (env('APP_USE_HTTPS')) {
    Log::info('Routes: forcing URLs to use https');
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}

Route::get('/', 'PublicController@getHome');
Route::get('home', 'PublicController@getHome');
```

Then in my PublicController.getHome() method I put this code:

```
public function getHome()
{
    $currentPath= Request::fullUrl();
    Log::info($currentPath);

    return view('public.home');
}
```

Now I go to my browser and enter this in the address bar:

```
https://www.example.com
```

And I get this in my log file:

```
AppServiceProvider: forcing URLs to use https
Routes: forcing URLs to use https
http://www.example.com
```

So as you can see from the last log message the fact that laravel always uses http instead of https is beginning to create issues. Starting with signed routes. I am trying to use the built-in Email Verification but the signature is being generated using https route and the email sent to user does have https in the url for going back to the same server. However the validation for the route is using http (even though https was used) so it generates a different signature and thus all verifications links fail with a 403 error.

Is there anything I am missing? I can't seem to find code that shows me how Laravel knows to use https or http or is it just hard coded for http?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

*** Update to show problem with Shaielndra Gupta answer ****

After implementing the middleware below is the code I used but as you will see the core problem exists in ALL methods dealing with url. So for example:

```
$request->secure()
```

returns false even when https was used. Then by calling:

```
redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
```

does no good because that will cause the route to loop back into this method again which still returns false for secure(), basically creating an infinite loop (or infinite too many redirects)

```
class ForceHttpsProtocol {

public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    Log::info('request uri: '.$request->fullUrl());
    Log::info('secure: '.($request->secure() ? 'yes' : 'no'));

    if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_USE_HTTPS')) {
        return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
    }

    return $next($request);
}

}
```

The log from the above code will produce the following when you make 1 attempt to go to any page even when using https://www.example.com

```
request uri: http://www.example.com
secure: no
request uri: http://www.example.com
secure: no
request uri: http://www.example.com
secure: no
request uri: http://www.example.com
secure: no
```

< over and over till page times out >

Comment: change ur `APP_URL=http://www.example.com` and `APP_USE_HTTPS=false
`

Comment: I must use https on my site. The goal here is to get methods inside Laravel to get the "actual" url being sent to the server, not changed to http. So we need laravel to recognize https in the url.

Comment: can you please share your host configration

Answer (score 6):

After much research I finally discovered what the issue is.
My live server is installed on an Amazon EC2 server **which is behind a Load Balancer**.
The load balancer is receiving the (https) request and handling all the SSL requirements and then forwarding the request to my website as http. 
To fix this issue I had to install the fideloper/TrustedProxy package. This package allows my site to trust the proxy and get the valid headers for the request so it now knows the request was actually sent using https.

Laravel wrote an article which describes my condition exactly.
https://laravel-news.com/trusted-proxy

This is the package I installed:
https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint! In newer Laravel versions, the functionality is included and the reverse proxy can be configured in the TrustProxies.php. Documentation on this is here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#trusting-all-proxies

Answer (score 0):

change in your `config/session.php`

```
'http_only' => true,
```

change it to

```
'http_only' => false,
```

or make a middlewere HttpsProtocol.php

```
namespace MyApp\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class HttpsProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure() && App::environment() === 'production') 
        {
             return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }
        return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

Then, apply this middleware to every request adding setting the rule at Kernel.php file in `protected $routeMiddleware array`,

```
'https'=>App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class
```

Comment: made no difference. I have tried it both ways. I am beginning to think this is a laravel bug.

Comment: can you clarify exactly what/where the code is changed in the Kernel.php file?

Comment: add all route inside this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'https'], function () {});`

Comment: so this is the change I made to my kernel,,,, its a little different from yours:     protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\ForceHttpsProtocol::class,
        ],

    ];

Comment: I will add an update to point out why your solution does not address the problem but rather the problem is in your solution as well.

Comment: I think this will work for you if not then the problem is with your certificate

Comment: I mean the code you gave me is executing as it should but the results is not what you think because the problem I am trying to fix exists in your code also. Please see update at end of my question for details. I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with certificate.

Comment: in other words please keep in mind we are NOT trying to change a http request to https..... we ARE sending https to start with.... We are simply trying to figure out where inside of Laravel is it converting the request url from https down to http. your solution simply creates a tug-of-war, we send https laravel thinks its http so we send it again as https but laravel still thinks its http so we are in a loop

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is struggling with apache proxy and `$request->server()`

you can overwrite Request lib default behaviour by add this line in `AppServiceProvider`

`$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on')`

Answer (score -1):

change This

```
APP_USE_HTTPS=true
APP_URL=https://www.example.com
```

to this

```
APP_URL=http://www.example.com
APP_USE_HTTPS=false
```

Because Laravel uses APP_URL to generate urls.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you buy it sounds like you are telling me not to use https on my website. If that is the case that is not an option.